# UITabbar with none item selected

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

Any one know how to create an app in such a way that when the application loads the uitabbr items are not selected(highlighted)..

need to display a view in window on load..no need to display tabbar item contents until click on tabbar button item..?

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present a modal view controller which hides the tab bar at startup. I think that's the best you can do with tab bar rules.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me.